# Protractor+Jasmin with angular2 E2E testcases

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, protractor, angular-cli

I am planning to use Protractor + Jasmin with Angular2 E2E testcases, which is fine using browser capability, but I really required to see Headless browser. As I know, PhantomJS is the one option to use Headless. But I really don't know how to conf in Protractor. Presently My Protractor Conf file is looking like below

```
/*global jasmine */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter')

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    '../e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {

    'browserName': 'chrome',
    /*browserName: 'phantomjs',
       version: '',
       platform: 'ANY'*/
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
  }
}
```

How to configure PhantomJS without opening browser? I guess this is most useful in all the CDCI PIPE line for deploying

Adding for this: I have add below code for phantomJS.

```
 capabilities: {

    //'browserName': 'chrome',
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': 'dist/vendor/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args': ['--loglevel=DEBUG']

  },
```

when I have ran the protractor using ng e2e, I am getting the error below:

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.

> recoveries-app@0.0.0 pree2e /Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app
> webdriver-manager update

selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

> recoveries-app@0.0.0 e2e /Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app
> protractor "config/protractor.conf.js"

[16:49:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1


/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:39
                throw new Error('browserName (' + this.config_.capabilities.browserName +
                      ^
Error: browserName (phantomjs) is not supported with directConnect.
    at Direct.setupEnv (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:39:23)
    at Runner.run (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:252:37)
    at TaskRunner.run (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/built/taskRunner.js:108:27)
    at createNextTaskRunner (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js:208:28)
    at /Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/built/launcher.js:235:13
    at _fulfilled (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "e2e" "--" "config/protractor.conf.js"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! recoveries-app@0.0.0 e2e: `protractor "config/protractor.conf.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the recoveries-app@0.0.0 e2e script 'protractor "config/protractor.conf.js"'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the recoveries-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor "config/protractor.conf.js"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs recoveries-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls recoveries-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/nai628/BalaRequiredfiles/AngularCLIPOC/RecoveryProjectWorkSpaceUpdate_v1/customer-servicing-service/recoveries-app/npm-debug.log

Some end-to-end tests failed, see above.
```

Comment: Adding of the above: i have try to add like below:

Comment: `Error: browserName (phantomjs) is not supported with directConnect. at Direct.setupEnv `.  Remove `directConnect` from your config.

Comment: @Gunderson I think you should put it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Error: browserName (phantomjs) is not supported with directConnect. at Direct.setupEnv` .

You need to remove `directConnect` from your config.  These options are only supported on Chrome and Firefox.  View the [master config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js) and [server setup](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md) docs for more info.

Comment: thanks a lot the problem got solved based on your recommendation. i have commented directConnect from conf file and install Phantomjs in global way

Comment: @BalakrishnaTirumalasetti no problem, glad it helped.  Please see this doc: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers